# Unable to connect to wifi, but able to connect to android hotspot

Tags: wireless, 14.04

Previously, I have used ubuntu for a short while. And I have installed 14.04 back then and everything worked perfectly. I was able to connect to all wifi hotspots, to my router as well.

Today, after removing linux distro a couple of weeks ago, I installed ubuntu 14.04 back again and now I have this weird issue:

I am unable to connect to my routers wifi, even though nothing changed in it. All the settings are the same. I have tried to disable routers wifi security - didn't help. I have tried to set up android hotspot and was able to connect to it without any issues.
Where should I even start to dig in order to fix this problem?

My wifi card is Intel Wifi Link 1000bgn.

Settings of my wifi network (2.4GHz):
Network mode: mixed; 
Channel width: auto; 
Channel: 6; 
SSID broacast: enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get rid of this problem by hard resetting my router. Strange, but it worked...